# I want to highlight the countries in my openlayer map

Tags: openlayers

I am very new to openlayers, I want to make some countries already selected (with some color filled on the selected areas) when i open my page. I am using the GML layer with kml file as input. But still it doesn't seems like a perfect solutions to me. I am assuming i already have kml file which contains the boundary coordinates. 
Can some one help me to find this solution? if this is not the correct way please suggest me. I highly appreciate for any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have geodjango and country data on your database you can do this as below :

django view.py

```
clickedPoint = Point(x,y,srid = 4326)
whichCountry = CountryPolyon.objects.filter(the_geom__contains = clickedPoint)
```

then you can take geojson and u can add your map the country polygon. the last thing you must do is add the code of remove first polygon

```
map.vector.removeFeatures(map.vector.features);
```

it may be a long way but usefull way...hope you like it

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html) select some areas on mouse over. Maybe looking the source you can change the behaviour to select some areas on load the map.